# Surprising HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment issue

Tags: wpf

Why StackA works fine and not StackB from below code snippet?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackA">
        <Button Width="90"
                Height="50"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <Label Content="button" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackB" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Width="90" Height="50">
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="button" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

AFAIK..
HorizontalAlignment is member of FrameworkElement, should align the control by referencing it's parent composing element.

HorizontalContentAlignment is member of control itself, aligns its own content accordingly.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @VivekSaurav The question is posted on top of the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the default value for `HorizontalContentAlignment` for a `Button` is `Center`.

Your label IS left aligned inside its container,  but the container is sized to be just big enough to contain the label content, so alignment makes no difference. The button then centers that content.

If you set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`, you will see the label is left aligned within the button, since it has the whole button size to play with.

Comment: Yes, In StackB if I set the button HCA to Stretch then label is aligned as instructed. Thanks. I was wondering this container is owned by button and will be used by button's content only so why isn't the default value of button HCA be stretch ?!

Comment: The default HCA varies by control and is set to something sensible for that control. Buttons generally look best with their content centered.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `Button` is a `ContentPresenter`, think of this as another `Grid`. This is itself aligned to the `Center` of the `Button`.

Therefore, when you align your `Label` to the `Left`, this is actually **inside** the `ContentPresenter`, which is in the centre, so the alignment will have no effect.

`HorizontalContentAlignment` affects the `ContentPresenter` the label sits inside, not the `Label` itself.